# -webkit-tap-highlight-color in Windows Phone?

Tags: html, css, mobile

Is there an equivalent to `-webkit-tap-highlight-color` for Windows Phone 7 (Mango)? I'm writing a mobile site, and I'd like it to display the same way across all browsers, if possible.

I've tried `tap-highlight-color` and `-ms-tap-highlight-color`, neither worked.

Comment: i tried the exact same things on WP8 and 8.1, because it's logical. Unfortunately for us, IE does not function logical. I mean... a meta-tag, seriously?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I know this is late to answer, but I have an update.
The answer is still no, unfortunately.
However, IE10 on WP8 allows:

```
<meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no"/>
```

You can only disable the tap color, and it seems that you cannot customize the color.

Comment: [According to Microsoft](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2012/11/15/adapting-your-webkit-optimized-site-for-internet-explorer-10.aspx), "The tag is specific to Internet Explorer 10 on Windows Phone, and does not apply to Internet Explorer 10 on Windows."

Comment: fyi: This still works in IE11 on WP8.1 even if the official docs do not mention it.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, there is no such equivalent Microsoft propritary extension at this time for WP7.  If you take a look at the [Microsoft list of attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531207%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), you will see an absence of anything even touch related.

On the JavaScript side, the IE blog just about that [IE 10 will specify the pressure of a touch](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/09/20/touch-input-for-ie10-and-metro-style-apps.aspx). This might be the closest that we can get for the time being. For now, if you really wanted to do it with JavaScript you would have to keep track of the time that the mouse was down (what a pain).  The events you will need are MouseDown, MouseMove, and MouseUp.

Recommendation: If I were you I would go with progressive enhancement and not support it for WP7 at this time.  If it's a critical part of your app though, you may have to play around a bit with JavaScript to see if you can get something workable.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I figured but I figured it was worth a shot asking.

Answer (score 5):

You can disable tap highlight in IE 10 on specific element with CSS

```css
-ms-touch-action: none;
```

Comment: I don't know about you, but my Windows Phone 7 doesn't have IE10.

Comment: as I see the answer is flagged, does this work for WP7 or only for devices using IE10?

Comment: This actually prevents all touch actions, so you can't scroll via touch. Check out @girlie_mac answer which is sourced from Microsoft's Windows blog.

Answer (score 1):

In windows phone 8.1 the meta tag did not worked (PhoneGap App).

```
  <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no"/>
```

But this in the CSS file worked for me

```
body{
  -ms-user-select: none
}
```

Answer (score -2):

The (-webkit-)tap-highlight property is only supported in [Safari on iOS (iPhone/iPad)](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/StandardCSSProperties.html#//apple_ref/css/property/-webkit-tap-highlight-color) and other browsers that use webkit.

If you're really desperate to display the tap highlight color you could use CSS' :focus selector which is the closest solution to your problem or try to achieve the same behavior with javascript (jQuery).