# IE 10 equivalent of -webkit-tap-highlight-color

Tags: html, css, webkit, internet-explorer-10

both IE 10 and iPad are highlighting touched areas. With `-webkit-tap-highlight-color` you can easily disable gray highlight on the iPad.

**Question**

What is the equivalent for **IE**? I want to disable the white focus rectangle for specific links only, like previos/next buttons on image slide shows.

I already tried blur functions on `click` and on `mousedown`, but that does not work. Also `-ms-touch-action` does not do the trick (tested on IE 10 on desktop)

Comment: possible duplicate of [-webkit-tap-highlight-color in Windows Phone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508100/webkit-tap-highlight-color-in-windows-phone)

Comment: `-ms-touch-action` does not seem to work for IE 10 on desktop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually came up with the answer.

You need to define the background on the `:active` selector like this:

```
.btnNext a:active
{
    background: none;
}
```

Simple like this :)

Comment: Well this does solve the problem in your case but I'd just like to add that it could instead cause problems with a lot of links with icons or links as buttons.

Answer (score 10):

From [Microsoft's](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2012/11/15/adapting-your-webkit-optimized-site-for-internet-explorer-10.aspx) website:

```
<meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
```

Comment: Microsoft documents are for IE10. However this works for IE11 too.